# What do I call a building with a variable number of storeys?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

I'm translating the description of a city block design. The city block (in this particular case) is basically a single building with a variable number of storeys: different sections of this block-sized building have different floor counts.

There's the expression "peremennoy etazhnosti" (переменной этажности) in Russian for this, meaning "of variable floor-count". In a verbatim translation, "of variable *storicity*".

What could be an English expression for this? Is there a commonly used expression, or should it be translated as-is, "with a variable number of storeys"?

> The general design concept of the Solnechny city district provides for the construction of [City Block 1.3](https://www.sunnydom.ru/), a perimeter block **with a variable number of storeys**.

I've been googling using different word combinations, but failed to find commonly used English expressions for these types of building.

For instance, I googled for "building with sections of different height", but still the result is gibberish.

Comment: I dont think there's a commonly used expression, and *a variable number of storeys* makes it sound as though there is a guy in a control room making it expand and contract, at least to me.

Comment: @Minty - but there *must* be some English expression that would make Google Images show such buildings. After all, it's a very common design.

Comment: Is there an architecture SE or something like that? There may be an English expression - as I say I don't think there's a commonly used one, but there could be one that an architect or civil engineer would use.

Comment: This question (a) shows reasonable signs of research; (b) while being obviously heavily into the _architecture_ domain, does, as you say in a comment, refer to a common design and so requires a reasonably common descriptor (so is valid also on ELU); and (c) has a reasonable chance of a reasonable answer. I wish all questions met these requirements. +1. (You may need to contact an architectural association for an answer, though.)

Comment: FWIW, The first image I examined in a Google Image search for << variable number of storeys >> (no quotes) had the descriptor "Modern five-porch monolithic-panel residential house of variable number of storeys in Moscow".

Comment: Excellent question. Buildings like that are exceedingly common in architecture dating from the last 20–30 years here, but I don’t have a word for it in my vocabulary either. You would think there’d be one, but I agree with Minty: _variable_ doesn’t work. Barring extensions being built, no building has a _variable_ number of floors once construction is complete. I think I’d just have to rephrase and say, “a perimeter block made up of sections of varying height” or something along those lines.

Comment: staggered height might provide exanples.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but the Wikipedia entry for [city block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_block) has this description: "City blocks are the space for buildings within the street pattern of a city, and form the basic unit of a city's urban fabric." If this applies to your case, the city block is not one building; there may be several buildings of different heights within the city block.

Comment: But such buildings *don't* have a variable number of storeys. They have exactly how many storeys as the roof reaches to—it's just that some of the lower-level floors don't take up the entire area of the building. Those storeys, whatever their size, still *exist*. If half of the building goes to one height, and half the other, than qualifying language would be used to describe each half.

Comment: This kind of thing is **not** about a term. It's about coming up with a good written description. I daresay that in English, we would refer to the height of the building in terms of the sections of roof aka roof sections.

Comment: For example: urban block building with roof sections of varying heights.

Comment: Multi story building?

Comment: @CowperKettle You also need to clarify what you mean by "city block": is it the patch of land enclosed by four streets? Or does it mean a single building like the British "block of flats"?

Comment: Wikipedia describes the [Sears Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willis_Tower)'s structure as [bundled tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_(structure)#Bundled_tube).

Comment: A building with set-backs, perhaps.

Comment: Set-backs typically refer to the position of the building on the lot.  For example a house may have a 50 foot setback requirement, which means It can be built no closer than 50 feet to the edge of the lot.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the term asymmetrical, though it would require follow-up explanation. "The city block is comprised of one asymmetrical building that is divided into sections of varying levels."

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing; here's why:

If it's a single building, as you say, then the total number of stories†  doesn't change.  The total is the total.  A building may be, for example, seven stories on one side and only five on another, but we would nonetheless say it's a seven-story building because the total number of stories remains seven.  Part of the structure being fewer stories doesn't decrease the total number of stories the building has.

Willis Tower in Chicago is 110 stories.  The fact that it has sections that are only 50 stories, 66 stories, and 90 stories doesn't diminish its count of 110 stories or lead anyone to call it anything other than a 110-story building.  That would remain true even if there were a hole creating a giant courtyard, as it were, in the middle of this building that takes up an entire city block.

That said, if you wish to clarify that there are sections that have fewer stories, then you simply say that.  You could say something like, "The block is a courtyard building whose north tower has seven stories and whose remaining towers have five."

†  I'm American, so I'm using the American spelling "story" rather than the British spelling "storey," along with the American plural spelling "stories" rather than the British plural spelling "storeys."

Comment: So is it proven then? American English is just another story.

Answer (score 1):

**What do I call a building with a variable number of storeys?**

*The general design concept of the Solnechny city district provides for the construction of City Block 1.3, a perimeter block with a variable number of storeys.*

---

If I am understanding this correctly the translation means, **a perimeter block where the (variable) number/amount, of storeys can be changed** I presume this item of change is regarding one building can be of a different amount of storeys than an adjacent building. Rather than in the afternoon it has more stories than in the morning.

In which case I think a better translation would be

**a perimeter block with a undefined number of storeys**.

> **undefined**; [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undefined) adjective: not clearly described, stated, or known:

*The general design concept of the Solnechny city district provides for the construction of City Block 1.3, a perimeter block with a undefined number of storeys*

Answer (score -1):

"Multistory" complex/building.

Multistory meaning having more than two stories.

Comment: Please could you add a link to that definition? I wouldn't call a house with two or three floors multistory.